# Simplying implicit functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

I have the following implicit expression that I wish to simplify:
$$
\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y{}^{2}}}=b
$$

I want to express this explicitly. This is what I did thus far:
$$
\frac{(x+y)^{2}}{x{}^{2}+y^{2}}=b^{2}$$

or 
$$
x^{2}+y^{2}+2xy=b^{2}x^{2}+b^{2}y^{2}
$$
or 
$$
2xy=x^{2}(b^{2}-1)+y^{2}(b^{2}-1)
$$

No matter what I do now, I cannot seem to get a 'clean' expression.
Any thoughts are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *explicitly* you mean writing $y$ as a function of $x$, note that
$x^{2}+y^{2}+2xy=b^{2}x^{2}+b^{2}y^{2}$ is a quadratic equation in $y$. Just solve it.

Comment: See the [solution in WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28x%2By%29%2F%28%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2By%5E%7B2%7D%7D%29%3Db+for+y).